# How to group radio buttons on different LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, radio-button

The problem that I have is how to group these radiobuttons. They are on different LinearLayouts because the way I populate the screen is by doing a for loop to get the ImageView and TextView in place.

Please help me out?

Here's the code.

```
private void initialize() throws JSONException{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json"));
    candidates = json.getJSONArray("candidates");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vote_list, null);
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollviewlist);
    LinearLayout main_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    main_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    String fullname = null, position = null, image = null, prev = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<candidates.length();i++){
        JSONObject o = candidates.getJSONObject(i);

        fullname = o.getString("lastName") + ", " + o.getString("firstName");
        position = o.getString("positionName");
        image = o.getString("image");

        if(!position.equals(prev)){
            TextView pos = new TextView(this);
            pos.setText(position);
            pos.setTextSize(20);
            pos.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            main_layout.addView(pos);
        }

        LinearLayout child = new LinearLayout(this);
        child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        child.setPadding(15, 5, 5, 5);
        child.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        name.setText(fullname);
        name.setTextSize(13);
        name.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        name.setWidth(210);

        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText("Vote");

        ImageView profImage = new ImageView(this);
        profImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        profImage.setMaxHeight(60);
        profImage.setMaxWidth(60);
        if(image.equals(""))
            profImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
        else{
            Bitmap bmp;
            byte[] img = Base64.decode(image.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
            profImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

        child.addView(profImage);
        child.addView(name);
        child.addView(rb);

        main_layout.addView(child);

        prev = position;
    }
    sv.addView(main_layout);
    setContentView(v);
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollviewlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer" >
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/votenow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below xml element in your layout file:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RadioGroup_searchType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioButton_branchSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Branch Search" 
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioButton_ifscSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IFSC code search" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

in code you can use it like below:

```
RadioGroup_searchType=(RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup_searchType);
RadioGroup_searchType.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
    {
        switch (checkedId) 
        {
            case R.id.RadioButton_branchSearch:
            break;
            case R.id.RadioButton_ifscSearch:
            break;
        };
    }
});
```